# May I use a DFTB+ result as initial guess for HF or DFT in PySCF?

Tags: pyscf, dftb+

I would like to use the result of a DFTB+ calculation as an SCF initial guess calculation in PySCF.

Is there a way to generate the density matrix of the converged calculation and read it with PySCF to perform a subsequent HF or DFT calculation?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I am aware of. Hégély and Kállay studied the accuracy of tight-binding initial guesses in [Int. J. Quantum Chem. 122, e26782 (2021)](https://doi.org/10.1002/qua.26782) and found that the tight-binding guess has a similar level of accuracy to SAD.

Even though such an interface is not available, note that the extended Hückel ('huckel') guess in PySCF is basically a tight-binding guess; see [J. Chem. Theory Comput. 15, 1593 (2019)](http://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jctc.8b01089) for the theory.